# Wearable card frame issue while using with WearableListView

Tags: android, wear-os

I was trying to implement wearable listview. For each list items i tried to use cardframe(android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame). While scrolling, size of card frame expands automatically. What is solution for this?

This is my xml for WearableListView-:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_box="all">

<android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lv_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Layout for each items in listview-:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView
    android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_box="bottom" >

    <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_srp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_post"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="JOB POST"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="9sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_companyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="COMPANY NAME"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="9sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_exp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="EXPERIENCE"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="9sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CITY"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="9sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
</android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView>
```

﻿

Comment: How does it expand; vertically? Can you post a screenshot? Could be to do with the fact that your WearableListView has height android:layout_height="450dp" which is more than the height of the wearable. You should replace that with wrap_content. That will allow you to see more than one item per page if that's what you're after.

Comment: hey thanks. i have replaced wearableListView with GridViewPager. Basically i created a CustomAdapter class which extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter. and then i have inflated my custom layout for each row and column.